# How to add Fortify in CI/CD processes

Tags: fortify

can anyone help me? I am using Fortify Software Security Center 19.2.0.3191 and I need to add it in my CI/CD processes.

1. I can't find an api for starting scanning process
2. I can't find how after scanning create task in my Task manager, I have an api in task manager but don't know how to run it from fortify after scanning
3. I can't find an api for receiving scanning report